# Talend ETL - Extract new records being inserted into the table

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

[image]Hi,

I have created a Talend ETL job which uses a query to a tmap to insert records into a table called "loan_grouping". I am using a lookup in the tmap to the "loan_grouping" table to pull through already existing records.

What I need is a way to extract only the newly created and inserted records. I have found guides online which show how to pull the rejected records using the Catch lookup inner join reject option in the tmap - but I need the opposite - I need to show the successful records.

The expression I have used in the tmap is:

```
!row1.GROUP_REFERENCE.equals(row3.GROUP_REFERENCE)
```

But it still only gives me the rejected records. I've also attached a couple of screenshots. If anyone can help, I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused between inner join and filter of tMap component, as i understood, you dont need a filter, just an inner join and their accepted and rejected data, so you need to delete the condition `!row1.GROUP_REFERENCE.equals(row3.GROUP_REFERENCE)` from the filter box at the top right.
Since there is an inner join in this tMap, you cannot get all records in an output, we can have records that matches inner join and rejected records, so we can use tUnite after this tmap to merge the two outputs and get all data back or use the initial source:

```
                       lookup
                          |
tReplicate------(main)---tmap-------- (records that already have ref)
         \                  \
          \                  rejected (new records)
           \
            (all records)
```

Comment: Thanks for that - you're right, I am confused! So if I have understood your comment correctly, then by removing the filter, the inner join capture reject will show any results where the key field doesn't exist in both the source and lookup tables? Will this automatically send the 'new' records to the second output?

Comment: @monkeyb33f Im not sure what you mean by "new", but as you did, there is two outputs at the right, one with "catch lookup inner join" activated and the second with no catch, when a row from the main input have a `GROUP_REFERENCE` that match in the lookup input, it will be shown in the output with no catch, the rest of data will be delivred to the output that catch inner join rejects.

Comment: OK, I think I follow. So from the tmap I want the top output to have no catch, as I want all records to go into the table (on an insert ignore basis) regardless of whether the GROUP_REFERENCE already exists. On the second output I turn the catch on, and this will only show records where GROUP_REFERENCE doesn't exist already (i.e. the record is 'new' to the table)?

Comment: @monkeyb33f Updated answer !